# LINQ query expression to explicit dot-notation

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Could you tell me how transform the query below to Linq Method version :

```
 myResult =
    from table1 in db.TABLE1
    join table2 in db.TABLE2 on table1.TABLE2_ID equals table2.ID
    join table3 in db.TABLE3 on table1.TABLE3_ID equals table3.ID
    where table1.ACTIF == true
    select new MyClass
    {
         T1MyField1 = table1.MyField1,
         T1MyField2 = table1.MyField2,
         T2MyField1 = table2.MyField1,
         T2MyField2 = table2.MyField2,
         T3MyField1 = table3.MyField1,
         T3MyField2 = table3.MyField2,
         T3MyField3 = table3.MyField3
    }
```

**Update 1:**
I created a predicate :

```
 Expression<Func<IMyClass, bool>> predicate;
```

And I'd like apply it the the lambada but I think it's not possible with lambda syntax.

Comment: The method-chain version would be horribly long and complicated to read - why would you want to do that? =)

Comment: He wants the extension method based equivalent of this code.

Comment: See update 1 more explanation

Comment: Considering query expressions are simply syntactic sugar for dot-notation, there is no functional difference.

Comment: @J.Steen how can I use my function with then ?

Comment: As you're trying to use an expression for a code-only structure (`MyClass` and `IMyClass`) you'll probably run into issues where the LINQ provider is unable to translate the query to proper SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your edit: You can always mix the two styles as you like:

```
myResult = (from ... select new MyClass { ... }).Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) to decompile your current assembly with the query syntax to the method syntax query. Just go to options, and deselect 'Decompile query expressions'.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myResult = db.TABLE1
    .Join(db.TABLE2, t1 => t1.TABLE2_ID, t2 => t2.ID, (t1, t2) => new { Table1 = t1, Table2 = t2 })
    .Join(db.TABLE3, j => j.Table1.TABLE3_ID, t3 => t3.ID, (j, t3) => new { Table1 = j.Table1, Table3 = j.Table2, Table3 = t3 })
    .Where(row => row.Table1.ACTIF)
    .Select(row => new MyClass {
        T1MyField1 = row.Table1.MyField1,
        T1MyField2 = row.Table1.MyField2,
        T2MyField1 = row.Table2.MyField1,
        ...

    });
```

Comment: Ew. But what the OP wants. =)